# Access data of a model linked through a OneToOneField model on a form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want a pre-populated form with the details (e.g. first name and surname) about the profile of a logged-in user, so that they can update them. I have a custom user model with first name and surname in it, and then a profile model which is linked to the user model and extends it, containing some extra information.

I've defined a constant within the profile model which theoretically should get the user's first name and surname.

models.py:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", unique=True, max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
[...]
    objects = UserManager()

[...]
```

**Profile model added**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='current_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def surname(self):
        return self.user.surname}

    def first_name(self):
        return self.user.first_name
[...]
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def profile_edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if p_form.is_valid():

            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated')
[...]
```

forms.py:

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('first_name', 'surname')
```

template.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div>
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}

          {{ p_form }}
          <button class="button" type="submit"> User update</button>
      </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

When accessing the template via the browser I expect to see the form already populated with the profile's (i.e. user's) first name and surname. Instead, I get a `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (surname, first_name) specified for Profile` in the shell.

--

**Answer**

User ruddra's answer works fine, and I've flagged it as the answer to my problem. Nevertheless, declaring two different form objects and printing them out in the template would also work:

views.py:

```
u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
```

forms.py:

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'surname')

class ProfileUpdateFormOld(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('image',)
```

template.html:

```
{{ u_form }}
{{ p_form }}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "a constant within the profile model". But the problem here is that first_name and surname are fields on User, not Profile; you should set `model = User` on the form.

Comment: @ruddra Apologies - I just realised that I forgot to include my Profile model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically those fields are from `User` model, they are not in `Profile` model. So you can change the model class in `ProfileUpdateForm` to `User`:

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'surname')
```

---

Updated answer based on comments:

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    surname = forms.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['first_name'] = self.instance.first_name()
        self.initial['surname'] = self.instance.surname()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('first_name', 'surname')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.instance.user
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        user.surname = self.cleaned_data.get('surname')
        user.save()
        return super(ProfileUpdateForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

Alternative to override the `__init__(...)` method is to send the initial data when initiating the form, pass the initial data. For example:
    profile = request.user.profile

```
ProfileUpdateForm(instance=profile, initial={'first_name':profile.first_name(), 'surname': profile.surname()})
```

Comment: But I want the logged in user to access their profile information, which will contain way more information (e.g. a picture, bio, etc.), not the user information. I already have a UserUpdateForm for doing what you suggest. I want the user to be able to change data coming from both their user and their profile models.

Comment: Thank you, I actually solved just by adding another Meta class to the form, i.e: ```class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'surname')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('image',)```

I'm willing to try your solution though. As it is now I get a `super(): no arguments` error.

Comment: uh, probably you are not user python3. please see the updated answer.

Comment: And I already added the arguments earlier when I first got the error. I get a `name 'self' is not defined` error.

Comment: opps, my bad. I made a mistake in code. updated my answer

Comment: Great, much better! Now I see all the fields. One last problem (not insignificant): the fields are not populated. If I input a new name and surname it will be saved; if I refresh the page, though, the fields becomes empty again. This happens only for the fields coming from the user model. The other fields coming from the profile model are correctly populated.

Comment: It's weird because even if I set `self.initial['first_name'] = 'test'`, the first_name field is empty on the template. I'm at a loss.

Comment: please check the update section again... hope it works

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, it just gets ignored! So frustrating. I use a similar thing for another form, with initial values set like that, and it works correctly.

Comment: Before all this, when I had the separated forms (one for user one for profile) it was working correctly. Now it's now working even if I revert back to my previous two-forms solution. What could it be!? Cache? Stale data? So strange.

Comment: OK, there was something fishy going on with my Python virtual environment. I deleted the sqlite database and all the migrations, I deactivated the virtual environment, activated it back, made and applied the migrations, recreated users etc, and it's now finally working. Thanks!